# Javascript/.NET regex

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex

I need a Javascript and .NET regex that checks a string and lets me know if the string only containers one character other than a space.

I want to prevent users from entering something like "wwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww" but  allow them to enter things like "cccccccc ddddddddd".

I'm so bad at regex, so I'm sorry for not coming with code.

Comment: A little confused by your question...will you allow up to one space character? Would you allow no space characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 string [] inputs = {" sdfasf asdf ", " wwwwww wwwwwww ", " aaaaa bbbb ccccccc"};
 foreach (string input in inputs)
 {
    var match = Regex.Match (input, @"^\s*(\w)(?:\1|\s)*$");
    Console.WriteLine (input + "\t" + match.Success);
 }
```

The regex doesn't use any special characters and I believe it will work in javascript as well.  In C#, it prints:

```
sdfasf asdf    False
wwwwww wwwwwww         True
aaaaa bbbb ccccccc     False
```

Comment: Your regex will match "wwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww wwwwwwwwwww" which is what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: This is right, though the OP may want to use "\S" instead of "\w".

Comment: @Darin I think he wants to *match* that string so that it can be disallowed.  In other words, he wants the regex to detect the illegal input.

Comment: @Pointy, but then this contradicts with "aaaaa bbbb ccccccc" for which this regex returns false.

Comment: I agree.  What's wrong with if it matchs, fail?  I can rewrite it if he can't do this, but it's easier to understand this way.

Comment: I think this solution provides what the OP wants, though he may need to use the whether the regex fails rather than succeeds.

Comment: okay, so the answer gives the opposite of what is asked for, but it's still a good answer because all you need now is to negate the result (ie `!match.Success`), and you'll have what you want.

Comment: I think I need to manipuate the regex a little bit to work in javascript. Are they escape characters correct for javascript?